# Magento 2.2.4: You need to choose options for your item

Tags: magento2

won't be able to add product to cart. I always got "You need to choose options for your item.". I am sure i have select all the required options.

This is the parameters i got when submitting the add to cart form.

```
         array(10) {
        ["uenc"]=>
          string(80) "aHR0cDovLzIwNi4xODkuMjA5LjYzLzIwLTktb3otaDJnby1jb25jb3JkLXRoZXJtYWwtYm90dGxlcw,,"
          ["product"]=>
          string(5) "15343"
          ["selected_configurable_option"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["related_product"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["form_key"]=>
          string(16) "88DObwCS6oMd7vJj"
          ["super_attribute"]=>
          array(1) {
            [983]=>
            string(3) "469"
          }
          ["options"]=>
          array(3) {
            [130]=>
            string(3) "524"
            [131]=>
            string(3) "526"
            [139]=>
            array(3) {
              ["month"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["day"]=>
              string(0) ""
              ["year"]=>
              string(0) ""
            }
          }
          ["qty"]=>
          string(2) "24"
          ["validate_datetime_139"]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["options_140_file_action"]=>
          string(8) "save_new"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think after you did a reimport / configuration of configurable product , you messed with the attributes assigned . It means one /many of simple products dont have the attribute assigned, but the main configurable have 2 attributes required. 
For solving that:

1. If you aren`t using the second attr on configurable product, remove it from database.
2. If you are using the second attr, then you should assign the attributes on each simple product
3. You can Delete the products and do the reimport correctly .

Comment: is there a way to print that attribute on addProduct function? so i know which attribute to check.

Comment: The best way for doing that is to search for the product id in this table : **catalog_product_super_attribute** , opening the id will show the attributes that configurable product has . If you dont know exactly what name correspond those attributes , go to **eav_attribute** table , search the attribute and see what name has , than you delete the one you dont want to be assigned on the **catalog_product_super_attribute**  table for the specific product you already searched , and should be good to add your products to cart .

Comment: I found only 1 attribute_id. It is 983 the same as above.

Comment: What about simple products , how much attributes has each of them  ?Have 
 you created any additional attribute to show on Product Edit ? If so try to disable it and check.

Comment: for the simple product, I only have 1 attribute. The color attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your help. already fixed the issue.

Comment: Im glad you fix it :). What was the issue ?

Comment: it was the additional attribute. I made a mistake with the name of a select element.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you mark the response as useful ? :)